# Params for multiple filters

Tags: javascript, angular

I have problem when I try to set params to URL for filtering table.

I create reusable method for handle this, but I have problem when I have multiple object for set to params... here is example

My params look like this

```
defaultParams = {
    page: '0',
    pageSize: '5',
    sortBy: 'username',
    sortByType: 'ASC',
    search: null,
    filter: {
      enabled: null,
      activated: null,
      student: {   --> this obj
        id: 1
      },
      role: {    --> this ob
        role: 'ADMIN'
      }
    }
  };
```

Problem is when I have multiple objects in filter obj, here you can see

My URL needs to look like this

```
?page=0&pageSize=5&sortBy=username&sortByType=ASC&filter=student.id:1,role.role:ADMIN
```

But I get like this

```
?page=0&pageSize=5&sortBy=username&sortByType=ASC&filter=student.id:1,student.role.role:ADMIN
```

I get here for role also STUDENT --> `student.role.role:ADMIN` instead of `role.role:ADMIN`

Here is [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxb5mg), in the console you can see problem

How to handle this?

Thnx

**StackSnippet**

```js
const params = defaultParams = {
  page: '0',
  pageSize: '5',
  sortBy: 'username',
  sortByType: 'ASC',
  search: null,
  filter: {
    enabled: null,
    activated: null,
    student: { // -- > this obj
      id: 1
    },
    role: { // -- > this ob
      role: 'ADMIN'
    }
  }
};

const isObject = o => {
  return (!!o) && (o.constructor === Object);
}


const buildFilterParams = obj => {
  let filterParams = '';
  const keyCount = Object.keys(obj).length;
  let count = 1;

  for (const key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key];

    if (!isObject(value)) {
      if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {

        filterParams += `${key}:${value}`;
        if (keyCount > count) {
          filterParams += ',';
        }
      }

      count = count + 1;
    } else {
      filterParams += `${key}.`;

      console.log(filterParams)

      buildFilterParams(value);
    }
  }
};
buildFilterParams(params)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with nested looping, it is still holding previous loop value and binding it to next result.
several solution to this issue

1. clearing filterParams value in else block

```
defaultParams = {
    page: '0',
    pageSize: '5',
    sortBy: 'username',
    sortByType: 'ASC',
    search: null,
    filter: {
      enabled: null,
      activated: null,
      student: {
        id: 1
      },
      role: {
        role: 'ADMIN'
      }
    }
  };


  buildFilterParams(defaultParams);

    
  function buildFilterParams(obj) {
  let filterParams = '';
    const keyCount = Object.keys(obj).length;
    let count = 1;

    for (const key in obj) {
      const value = obj[key];

      if (!this.isObject(value)) {
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {

          filterParams += `${key}:${value}`;
          if (keyCount > count) {
            filterParams += ',';
          }
        }

        count = count + 1;
      } else {
        filterParams += `${key}.`;

        console.log(filterParams)
        
        this.buildFilterParams(value);
        filterParams = ''; // clearing the value
      }
    }
  }

  function isObject(o) {
    return (!!o) && (o.constructor === Object);
  }
```

2. Caching the value of previous function return and adding in to next recursion.

```
  var filterParams = '';
defaultParams = {
    page: '0',
    pageSize: '5',
    sortBy: 'username',
    sortByType: 'ASC',
    search: null,
    filter: {
      enabled: null,
      activated: null,
      student: {
        id: 1
      },
      role: {
        role: 'ADMIN'
      }
    }
  };


  console.log(buildFilterParams(defaultParams));


  function buildFilterParams(obj) {
    const keyCount = Object.keys(obj).length;
    let count = 1;

    for (const key in obj) {
      const value = obj[key];

      if (!this.isObject(value)) {
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {

          filterParams += `${key}:${value}`;
          if (keyCount > count) {
            filterParams += ',';
          }
        }

        count = count + 1;
      } else {
        filterParams += `${key}.`;
        filterParams+= this.buildFilterParams(value);
         if (keyCount > count) {
            filterParams += ',';
          }
        //console.log(filterParams)
        
        //filterParams = '';
      }
    }
    return filterParams;
  }

  function isObject(o) {
    return (!!o) && (o.constructor === Object);
  }
```

Comment: **@mplungjan **

Please check and update your thoughts. Let me know incase if you need a better way to implement it.